# Revert a file to a specific revision and check log of the file in git

Tags: git

I am trying to revert a file in git a particular version using
`git checkout <version> -- filename`.
Then I am checking the history of that file by doing `git log filename` . 
But the log still shows the history of the file including the latest version . 
I want to revert file to a particular version and show the log history (`git log filename` )from that `version` . 
Can anyone pls help

Answer (score 0):

Just because you restore the file content to a previous version doesn't change the fact that there were commits on the file since then. If you just want to obtain the log for `filename` until `version`, use this:

```
git log version -- filename
```

To obtain the log for the last 20 commits before `version`:

```
git log -20 version -- filename
```

Comment: How can I know to which version the file has been reverted to ?

Comment: @Newbie: **you told** git which version to checkout with `git checkout <version>`. What do you need to know more??

Comment: If I forget that revision number(version) and come back later to check to which version the file belongs to , how can I know ?

Comment: you can't. If you feel the need for this, add the `version` to the commit message like `resetting <filename> to <version>`

Comment: in P4V we can know what is the current version of the file .Is there a same way to know that in GIT ?

Comment: @Newbie: there's no file version in git. The version represents the state of the repository. So it is not possible to tell "file 1 is in version 44 while file 2 is in version 55". There's only the state of the **repository**. Since this is obviously new to you, you should read http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics where this is discussed.